# how to access remote cgi from PHP script?

Tags: php

I'm totally rookie as to PHP. I want to write a PHP script in which it can access a remote cgi via http to get some data. I know that PHP is able to fopen any remote URL and fetch file content, but I concern about the result returned by cgi script, not the script itself.

Comment: What do you mean by 'result returned' ?

Comment: cgi program is executed by http server and anything the cgi program print out to stdout will become the content displayed in web browser, I mean this kind of 'return'. not the return code (int).

Comment: Don't rely on fopen/file_get_contents to be able to open remote URLs. In shared hosting environments it might be disabled.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: thanks , but what is the right way to do that?

Comment: CURL is the best way since you don't have to deal with raw HTTP.
However, it's an extension so a few hosts might not have it enabled.

But since fsockopen and the other socket functions are also likely to be disable in shared hosting, the best way would be the one that works on your host.
On the other hand, curl has the least chances of causing security issues so getting a new hosting provider to enable that might be easier than getting him to enable socket functions / allow_url_fopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening and retrieving a URL *is* the output of the script, it is what your web browser does when you open a PHP page. Retrieving the script itself is normally not possible - it would be a security vulnerability if everyone could read your source code.